# Django View return to self on error

Tags: django

Working on a seemingly simple Django view but keep getting errors.

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            "user_form": UserForm(),
            "contact_form": ContactForm(),
            "company_form": CompanyForm(),
        }

        return render(request, "accounts/registration_form.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and contact_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
            self.form_valid()
        else:
            self.form_invalid(user_form, contact_form, company_form)

    def form_valid(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/registration-complete")

    def form_invalid(self, user_form, contact_form, company_form):
        context = {
            "user_form": user_form,
            "contact_form": contact_form,
            "company_form": company_form
        }

        return render_to_response(self.request, "accounts/registration_form.html", context)
```

When I check user_form, contact_form and company_form on `is_valid()` I can see that company_form is not valid so I go to the `form_invalid()` method.
Here I should be redirected to the same view with the data prefilled and some errors shown on the screen.

Now I get an error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/`
When I replace

```
return render_to_response(self.request, "accounts/registration_form.html", context)
```

with

```
return render(self.request, "accounts/registration_form.html", context)
```

I get another error message:

```
ValueError at /accounts/register/
The view accounts.views.RegistrationView didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Which makes perfect sense, but I'm not sure how to solve this one. 
I hope there is an easy solution for this.

Comment: Do you have a template at `accounts/registration_form.html`? The error suggests that Django can't find that template.

Comment: @solarissmoke Yes I do. I use the same template in the get()  method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are calling `render`; that *does* return an HttpResponse. The issue is that your `post` method does not return the value of calling `form_valid()` (or invalid).

```
if user_form.is_valid() and contact_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
    return self.form_valid()
else:
    return self.form_invalid(user_form, contact_form, company_form)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `post` method you actually have to `return` the results of calling either `form_valid` or `form_invalid`:

```
    if user_form.is_valid() and contact_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid()
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(user_form, contact_form, company_form)
```

Otherwise your `post` method doesn't return anything at all!